# How to use same Outlet for different size classes in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a requirement in which i want to show different UI for iPhone & iPad so instead of using different story boards i have used different size classes.I have few labels on both iPhone & iPad.Values of label is set at runtime so i have used outlet for this.I have a single view controller with size classes so that i can switch between different screen on iOS.Now i am able to connect only one outlet for either of the device.If i connect outlet for iPhone then IPad outlet not work & vice versa.So please tel me how can i use same out for different using size classes?

Comment: add UILabel for size class heightAny*widthAny

Comment: See i don't want to use generic size class. I want to use diffrent size class.@sheshnath

Comment: then, i think add label for each class and connect with same outlet

Comment: It is not working i have done like this.I just works for only one device for which device last label was connected.@sheshnath

Comment: what about different outlet ?

Comment: Then i have to change the entire code & add conditions for selecting outlet on the basis of which type of device is running.Any simple solution?@sheshnath

Comment: i think best solution is use base class, but i donno why you don't want to use this.

Comment: Because i want seprate UI for iPad & iPhone.My UI On iPad is not exacltly same.I know using base class my code will work just fine but here i have diffrent situation.Apple introduced size classes then it must have provided some solution to this problem also.@sheshnath

Comment: you can have separate UI, but the label i think you need this in both(iPhone,iPad) UI, make this Label  for base class left over controls separate for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83931/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-shesh-nath).

Comment: I want diffrent uI for each device it means their size,alignment,position will be diffrent but label will remain the same.@sheshnath

Comment: You shouldn't set different objects to the same outlet - you should change the constraints so that the single object is positioned correctly on each device using size classes

Comment: @Paulw11 It's not possible to do this since you can't distinguish between iPhone 4/5/6 correctly just using size classes.

Comment: Add the labels in AnyWidth-AnyHeight class and then define specific constraints for the size classes you want.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem today and I found the solution  to it. In Attributes Inspector, we can choose a label to be installed in multiple size classes, like below:

[image: Install size classes]

Then the label will appear in the size classes you have installed, you don't have to add new labels for each size class. When you create/connect a outlet with the label, the outlet is shared in the installed size classes.

Comment: I think this does not work if you want your UILabel to be at a completely different location in the storyboard!

Answer (score 0):

I could not add this into comments so I am posting this as an answer.

Reading the comments what I can conclude is :

**You should use a Generic class** (`Any Width, Any Height`).

`Size classes` is a feature of `Interface Builder` which is responsible for presenting the `view` of your application. While the values to your `UILabel` are managed by the `Model`(actual value) and `Controller`(ViewController.m). So like it or not you have to bring the Controller into the picture.

Before posting this answer I tried to connect the two different labels to the same outlet and use the `viewWithTag:` method to set the outlets to correct views depending on the device the app is running on, it didn't work.

Below is the snippet I used **which didn't work**

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
    }
    else{
        _label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    }
```

Still as @sheshnath said, there is nothing wrong in using a Generic size class.